# Gridview Delete Button - Object Reference Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to develop a web page in asp .NET with a GridView. I want the GridView to have an edit and delete button. Following is my markup for GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="EduGrid" CssClass="edugrid table table-striped table-hover table-borderless" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" OnRowDeleted="EduGrid_RowDeleted" OnRowDeleting="EduGrid_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
                 <asp:CommandField SelectText="" ShowSelectButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-dark btn-sm fa fa-edit" />
                 <asp:CommandField DeleteText="" ShowDeleteButton="true" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-dark btn-sm fa fa-trash" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="degree" HeaderText="Degree" SortExpression="degree" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="major" HeaderText="Major" SortExpression="major" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="year" HeaderText="Passing Year" SortExpression="year" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="total marks" HeaderText="Total Marks" SortExpression="total marks" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="obt marks" HeaderText="Obtained Marks" SortExpression="obt marks" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="division" HeaderText="Division" SortExpression="division" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="board" HeaderText="Board/University" SortExpression="board" />
    </Columns>
                                
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="thead-dark" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Larger" />
    <RowStyle Font-Names="calibri" Font-Size="Medium" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I also have a label on the page "CandId" that contains ID to get records in GridView and delete the records from DataBase. But, as there are more than 1 records for each candidate, I want to delete the records on the base of 2 parameters i.e. ID & Degree (the first column). It deletes on the base of ID only but deletes all the records of that specific ID, but I only want to delete one specific entry. If I provide the degree column as a parameter, it gives an object reference exception. Following is my backend code in c#:

```
        protected void EduGrid_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = EduGrid.SelectedRow;
            conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            string query = "DELETE FROM [Edu Info] WHERE cnic = @cnic AND degree = @degree";
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnic", lblID.Text);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@degree", row.Cells[1].Text);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                lblInfo.Text = "Record deleted successfully.";
                lblInfo.Visible = true;
                Get_Edu();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblInfo.Text = "An error occurred. Please contact the administrator.";
                lblInfo.Visible = true;
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
                SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
            }
        }
```

I think the problem is that the method OnRowDeleting is not suitable to work with GridView.SelectedRow and that .SelectedRow can only work in the OnSelectedIndexChanged method. If that is the case and I am right, what should I do to fix it? Can anyone please provide a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [my tutorial](https://www.vanderwaal.eu/mini-projecten/gridview-edit-and-update-demo). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating. You can download a demo project from [GitHub](https://github.com/VDWWD/gridview-edit-and-update-demo) to get you started.

Comment: it does not have my answer @VDWWD. kindly provide an answer regarding my problem.

Comment: Yes it does. Did you look at the `GridView_RowDeleting`? It has `e.RowIndex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lot of issues here. And I not clear why your data source does NOT include the primary key of the database. And as a result, you should not need to use both cnic and degree to identify a row. I cannot EVER recall having rows in a grid in which I don't have a PK ID. (so, very strange on your part).

However, do keep in mind that the delete event does NOT change the selected index. In fact if you drop in say a button, use commandName/CommandText, you find that the row command fires FIRST (selected index not yet changed), and THEN the selected index event fires.

In your example - index will not change.

However, in that event, you can get the row clicked on with with this:

```
e.RowIndex
```

So, you can now go like this:

```
GridViewRow row = EduGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
```

So, the rest of what you have thus should be ok. So, just keep in mind that for command buttons, and most buttons in the grid, the selected index even (if it were to fire) in fact fires AFTER the button event stub. In some cases then you could in theory move the code to the selected index changed event - but that does not even fire in this case. So selected index is NOT available. Use e.RowIndex to get that row.

Also, if you include the PK from the datbase, then you don't need to use the two columns to identify that row in the datbase, but ONLY the PK row id. And you do NOT have to have the PK even display in the grid.

That's what DataKeyNames = "the PK row column name" is for"

eg:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" >
```

So, DataKeyNames = "PK FROM database"

Thus in above RowDeleting event, then

```
e.RowIndex - gets you row index clicked on
e.Keys["ID"]  - gets you database PK
```

So, note how you can (should) try and set the DataKeyNames  = "primary key" from database. then you can get with e.Keys["ID"] the PK row id.

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer, @Albert D. kallal. The reason I dont have PK in my data source is because the client does not want it in the grid. Also, I solved it using your answer by adding degree as a datakeyname. Thanks for the help !

Comment: That's good! So that is what DataKeys is for! You do not have to expose, or ever had the PK show up - even in the markup. If you set DataKeyNames="ID"? Then you have full use of the PK values, but they never appear in the grid, and you never expose them client side. So for security, and ease of use of PK row values? Datakeys is your magic carpet ride.

Comment: Yeah, I got that idea from your answer too. Now I am using PK as the DataKey but not showing it in the Grid.